# Как правильно: змееед или змееяд?

Tags: правописание, словообразование, словоупотребление

В русском языке есть слово, оканчивающееся на три "е" подряд: "длинношеее".

По поводу еще одного слова с тремя "е" подряд - "змееед" в интернете ведутся споры. Некоторые утверждают что слова "змее**Е**д" не существует, правильно писать "змее**Я**д".

И все-таки является ли правильным словом "змееед"? Или все-таки правильно "змееяд"? Есть ли разница в значении этих слов?

Comment: Почему же тогда буквоед, а не буквояд, ведь принцип один и тот же.

Comment: @СергейПавлов: the former is Russian, the latter is Church Slavonic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The bird of prey is definitely called *змееяд* or *орёл-змееяд* in Russian. I've never seen it called *змееед*, and it's not mentioned in the dictionaries.

It uses the OCS rendition of the second root, similar to *травоядное*, *тунеядец* etc.

If we're talking about a constructed word meaning "snake eater" in general, then it would make sense to render it *змееед* in Russian, as the pattern is productive and the corpus mentions words like *кошкоед*, *говноед*, *кармоед*, *бананоед* etc.

Using the same pattern, you could construct more words with three *е* in them, like *швееед* ("sempstress eater"), *фееед* ("fairy eater") etc. Some of them, like *орхидееед* or *сельдерееед*, would even make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Если речь про хищную птицу, то правильно змееяд. Окончание "яд" связано не с ядом, а с "яством" - едой. То есть, фактически, змееед. Но говорить надо именно через я.
Змееед можно применять к другим существам, поедающим змей. Напимер, к людям.

Answer (score 3):

"Змееяда" встречал один раз, в довольно старом переводе Майн Рида. И помню, если не ошибаюсь, более поздний перевод, где был уже "змееед". Не знаю, с чего бы считать "змеееда" неправильным. Похоже на новую находку наивных сетевых прескриптивистов.

Comment: I haven't read the book you're mentioning, but is it really about the bird of prey? Because the latter is definitely *змееяд* in Russian, and has always been.